# How do I remove one column from all the tables in dynamic copy data activity of a pipeline from the database

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to remove a column named 'EXT_DATA' from all the tables in a pipeline using the copy data activity in ADF. Since it's a dynamic pipeline, I'm unable to directly remove the column from mapping tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, using copy activity might involves complex approaches. As **copy activity cannot delete the columns dynamically from the mapping, you need to build the mapping JSON every time as per the incoming file columns** and it should be given under the mapping section.

Instead of this, you can use **Dataflow** where you can make use of **Select** transformation to achieve your requirement.

Create a dataflow and add your source and target to that dataflow (If your target does not support or needs any changes you can give a temp ADLS folder and later use copy activity to copy from that temp to your target location). Make sure the **source projection is empty** in the dataflow and **the `schema` in the dataset also empty** as well.

As you know the column that you want to delete, create a Rule-based mapping in the select transformation and give the condition `name!=<your_column_name>` and `$$` in the next expression like below.

[image]

Here, as we are using this dataflow for all files, the mapping should be empty that means number of columns should be `0`. For data preview, you can check with a sample data by importing the projection, but after checking, remove the projection and make sure the number of columns is `0`.

Take sink and add your target dataset and give the path till the target folder only. **For the dynamic file**, create a dataflow parameter and use that in the sink file settings like below.

[image]

Pass the file names from the pipeline to dataflow activity in the loop like below.

**Pass source dataset filename parameter:**

[image]

**Pass the target filename to the dataflow parameter that we created:**

Here, I am creating temporary files, so concatenated a `temp` before that. You can give the filename as per your requirement.

[image]

Debug the pipeline and the given column will be removed in the target files after the loop.

[image]